# How can I mount a FreeBSD disk in Ubuntu?

Tags: mount

I've got a hard drive from an old DVD player/recorder and I need to get the content off of it. It is in FreeBSD format. How can I mount this drive in Ubuntu in order to transfer the content to an NTFS drive for example?

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe ufs` and mount it normally with a mount command.

Comment: I'm rather new to this, sorry. How would the mount command look? The device is listed as /dev/sdb1

Comment: First, create a mount point: `sudo mkdir /mnt/myNTFSdrive`, then mount it: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myNTFSdrive`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/freebsd
sudo mount -t ufs -o ro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdaX /mnt/freebsd
```

`sdaX` = the freeBSD partition.